# Change highlight color

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

jQuery's highlight method will highlight any div with a yellow background.

How do I specify what color to use instead of yellow for highlight?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/highlight-effect/):

```
$(this).effect("highlight", {color: 'blue'}, 3000);
```

Comment: just wondering, how would I highlight the text only, not the background?

Comment: The example given in this answer is very easy to understand unlike the documentation on the page linked to above which is for the "highlight" effect and is very sparse. For more detail on .effect() itself see this page: http://api.jqueryui.com/effect/.

Answer (score 18):

```
$("div").click(function () {
    $(this).effect("highlight", { color: "#ff0000" }, 3000);
});
```

will highlight in red. It's all in the [documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight).

Comment: color = will give a syntax error. the notation is key: 'value'

Comment: sorry - i was too wound up in anonymous c# types in my head... ;) edited!

Comment: cheers guys. I was looking into the jqueryui documentation which is not as detailed as jquery's documentation

Answer (score 3):

FWIW I found that IE8 would give an error in jQuery 1.7.2 using`effect("highlight",...)` when the current color of the element was specified as text or when the highlight color was specified as text (i.e. `"blue"`) instead of in hex notation: `"#ff0000"`.

Answer (score 1):

```
       $('.divID').live('mouseover mouseout', function (event) {
        if (event.type == 'mouseover') {
            // do something on mouseover
          $(this).css({ "background-color": YOURCOLOR, "opacity": ".50" });

        }
        else {
            // do something on mouseout
             $(this).css("opacity", "100");

        }
      });
```

This will give the nice hover effect with opacity looks.